# Setting a Panel's background color from a class, Windows Forms - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have relating to setting the panels background color from a class.

The class is not within the form of the panel, but as a side class.

The panel on the main form is called pnlCanvas.

I don't know what I am missing. If I have values or methods in the main form, then I can access those values from the class. But, the panel seems it acts different.

---

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ChangeColor changeColor = new ChangeColor(this);

    changeColor.RedPanel();
}
```

---

```
class ChangeColor 
{
    public Form1 form1 { get; set; }
    public ChangeColor(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
    }
    Public void RedPanel()
    {
        form1.pnlCanvas.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change RedPanel to this: this.pnlCanvas.BackColor = Color.Red;

Comment: I see you edit your post to give more information, I'll give that a shot. Looks like it gives an error if I just use 'this'. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'ChangeColor ' does not contain a definition for 'pnlCanvas' and no extension method 'pnlCanvas' accepting a first argument of type 'ChangeColor ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Make this a member of Form1

```
    Public void RedPanel()
    {
        this.pnlCanvas.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Having the change color code within in form1 isn't a problem. Can I not have a standalone class outside of form1 change the properties of the panel of form1?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you believe that is the correct approach, you have serious architectural problems outside the scope of this question.

Comment: We are trying to build "blocks" that can be swapped in to do different functions. And the items on the form are not to see the code in the blocks. And one of the items we are trying to get working is displaying data to a panel from a standalone class(es).

Comment: Your blocks are not blocks - they are spaghetti code. If you truly believe that you need something like this, then pass the panel as an argument, and do not make reference to the form.

Comment: It is spaghetti code, they don't want to rewrite it from the ground up. It will be thrown away in few weeks. It was built as a test bed system with multiple ideas see if they could go anywhere with them. But thank you for the passing the panel as an argument. That solved that issue.